# Why does user mode linux spawn 4 processes?

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-machine

If I start User Mode Linux with this command:

```
./kernel32-3.19.8 ubda=./Debian-Wheezy-x86-root_fs mem=128m
```

On Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) with one CPU core, why do I see 4 processes in top:

```
 1608 root      20   0  132m  42m  42m S   0.7 33.4   0:12.01 kernel32-3.19.8
 1615 root      20   0  132m  42m  42m S   0.0 33.4   0:00.00 kernel32-3.19.8
 1616 root      20   0  132m  42m  42m S   0.0 33.4   0:00.02 kernel32-3.19.8
 1617 root      20   0  132m  42m  42m S   0.0 33.4   0:00.00 kernel32-3.19.8
```

Comment: Processes with the same amount of memory? They're probably threads of the same process, not processes. Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [User Mode Linux: skas mode](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/old/skas.html):

> If you run ps, you will notice only four processes per UML rather than the dozens that you see in tt mode. They are
>
> - The UML kernel thread, which runs in the separate kernel address space, executes kernel code, and does system call interception on UML processes
> - The UML userspace thread, which runs all UML process code and switches between host address spaces on each UML context switch
> - The ubd driver asynchronous IO thread
> - The write SIGIO emulation thread